# Replace laravel ORM to Spot

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get ride of Eloquent in order to use Spot ORM in my Laravel 5.1 application. The thing is I have no idea how to do that..
I have tried to find a provider package for Spot on Laravel but the only repository I found is https://github.com/Dijky/spot-service-provider (for Silex framework).

Maybe it is possible to begin with this provider and adapt it to the laravel framework? I am trying to find it, so if someone knows please can you help?

Thanks !

## Edit

Looking closer to the official github repository I found out there were already a laravel provider inside the provider directory

Comment: have you considered this `https://github.com/vlucas/spot2` and where are you feeling difficulty..?

Comment: Looking closer to the repository I found out there were already a laravel provider inside the provider directory :)